# Wordpress conditional .js

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I´m working on a wordpress page and depends of the situation it shows a vídeo or a picture. The goal is, when the navigator the client is using is **safari ** show the picture and in **the rest of the navigators** show the vídeo. Here is the code that works on desktop and android.

```
<video id="video" autoplay muted loop playsinline>
  <source src="https://elvientomedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/produccion-a-medida.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

<img id="imagen" src="https://elvientomedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/Clientes-10.png" alt="Imagen alternativa" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script>
if ("safari" in window && window.safari.pushNotification) {
 var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen');
 imagen.src('https://elvientomedia.es/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/Clientes-10.png')
 imagen.style.display = 'block';
 var video = document.getElementById('video');
 video.style.display = 'none';
} else {
 var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen');
 imagen.style.display = 'none';
 var video = document.getElementById('video');
 video.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

With the code I attached works just fine in desktop and android, the problem is when it´s open in iphone. In those cases doesn´t show nothing, doesn´t matter if I open it in chrome or safari, as long as I open it in iphone it just doesn´t show anything.

Comment: Aside from the problem - is there a specific reason you want to do this? The webm format is well supported in Safari, and has been for some time. There's no need to browser sniff to avoid it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but rather than using `display: none` you might consider changing `src` to `data-src` on your video and img, since no matter what browser is used, both will load, causing unnecessary asset download. You could use JS to load the `src` depending on the media element depending on the browser. Also, as Rory stated, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan! In this case, something unusual is occurring—it's not compiling properly. If you open this website in Safari, you'll notice a strange purple background behind the video. That's what I'm trying to avoid by using a picture instead of the video when open in safari or iphone.

Regarding what @disinfor said about the display, I will use that instead. Thanks for that mate

https://elvientomedia.es/